# aurelia webpack hot reload not working

Tags: webpack, aurelia, webpack-dev-server

My aurelia app does not seem to work with webpack hot loader:

```
Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

I could find the following ressources:

https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/629

http://blog.aurelia.io/2016/12/08/big-aurelia-release-update/

https://github.com/aurelia/hot-module-reload

So it should be possible by now, but I don't know what to do with the aurelia-hot-module-reload module after installing it.

Answer (score 0):

aurelia-hot-module-replacement is used by aurelia-loader-webpack 2.0.0.

to make it work, I think that we should just configure plugins well (at least what is working now)

I didn't dig some mutch into this repo https://github.com/jods4/aurelia-webpack-build, but maybe is working maybe not